# Converting XML Spring config for JMX to Java config

Tags: java, spring, jmx

I have a small test app for exposing a "Bean" to JMX using Spring. It uses an XML based config  and everything works fine:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.dmclaughlin.spring" />
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:test.properties"/>

<bean id="SimpleJmxController" class="com.dmclaughlin.spring.jmx.SimpleJmxBean">
    <property name="activated" value="${some.activated}"/>
</bean>

<!--  Spring JMX -->
<bean id="exporter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter" lazy-init="false">
  <property name="autodetect" value="true"></property>
  <property name="namingStrategy" ref="namingStrategy"></property>
  <property name="assembler" ref="assembler"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="attributeSource"
 class="org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationJmxAttributeSource"/>
<bean id="assembler"
 class="org.springframework.jmx.export.assembler.MetadataMBeanInfoAssembler">
  <property name="attributeSource" ref="attributeSource"/>
</bean>
<bean id="namingStrategy"
 class="org.springframework.jmx.export.naming.MetadataNamingStrategy">
  <property name="attributeSource" ref="attributeSource"/>
</bean>
```

But the application I need to add this functionality to, uses @Configuration style, and I'm trying to convert the above XML to work. I added something like this:

```
@Bean
public MetadataNamingStrategy getNamingStrategy() {
    MetadataNamingStrategy strategy = new MetadataNamingStrategy();
    strategy.setAttributeSource(new AnnotationJmxAttributeSource());
    return strategy;
}

@Bean
public MetadataMBeanInfoAssembler getMbeanInfoAssembler() {
    return new MetadataMBeanInfoAssembler(new AnnotationJmxAttributeSource());
}

@Bean
public MBeanExporter getExporter() {
    MBeanExporter exporter = new MBeanExporter();
    exporter.setAutodetect(true);
    exporter.setNamingStrategy(getNamingStrategy());
    exporter.setAssembler(getMbeanInfoAssembler());
    return exporter;
}
```

And everything compiles, but when I load up JConsole my Bean annotated with @ManagedResource and @ManagedAttribute isn't exposed. Am I missing something simple here?

*Edit*: the answer below didn't fix my problem (the problem was I was testing my XML in a Tomcat environment, but testing my non-XML config in a standalone application, which meant there was no JMXServer present.. d'oh), but it did help me simplify once I debugged what I  messed up.

Comment: is your issue resolved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For [me](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2011/01/spring-framework-without-xml-at-all.html) it was enough to add:

```
@Bean
public AnnotationMBeanExporter annotationMBeanExporter() {
    return new AnnotationMBeanExporter();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work for me either. I have a "ServiceImpl" annotated with @ManagedResource and it's being found by the IoCProvider.. so I'm not sure why it doesn't appear in jConsole.

Answer (score 0):

you should configure your mbeanexporter with "eager"

```
@Bean
@Lazy(false)
public MBeanExporter getExporter() {
...
}
```

greetings

AccLess